# Query not working in live site but working on local

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have used WPLMS theme in my server site. First I have created a custom post like WPLMS course type in my local. After that, I have used below code on my localhost in the functions.php and it's working well. Live site post type and localhost post type is same, but the same code is not working in the live site. Maybe live course type disable this query. How can I fix this?

```
$args = array("post_type" => "course", "s" => $course);

    $qr = new WP_Query($args);
    //var_dump($qr);
    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($qr);
    echo "</pre>";
    echo $post_type = $qr->query['post_type'];
    echo $post_id = $qr->posts[0]->ID;
    var_dump($post_type);
    var_dump($post_id);
    wp_reset_postdata();
```